# OpenSC API documentation, tutorial

Tags: javacard, opensc

In last couple months while learning to develop *Java Card* applets I managed to develop *ISO 7816* compatible file system applet. I successfully implemented most of the standardized APDU commands from 7816-4, -8, -9 standards (I used other available functional descriptions and standards like *OpenPGP applet, IAS ECC, MUSCLE, CoolKey* etc. to help me understand former standards).

Now I am trying to develop **PKCS#11** implementation for this my own applet. I am familiar with using **OpenSC** tools for already supported cards (opensc-tool, opensc-explorer, pkcs15-init, pkcs15-tool etc.). But I would like to develop ***driver for this applet for OpenSC***.

I browsed information available on their project site on github and found some documentation on implementing custom driver for OpenSC (entersafe card example, and general suggestions for card driver implementation). Also I found that on gooze.eu there were available some tutorials on OpenSC, but this site is no longer available.

So my questions are:

- Where can I find some more information on OpenSC API in order to understand available driver code and to manage to develop my own?
- Any general overview of API, about OpenSC architecture, description of available functions (description on intended usage of structures and functions such as sc_format_apdu, sc_transpit_apdu, sc_card_operatins as an example etc.) to give me a jumpstart for understanding OpenSC source code and implementing a card driver.
- Are there any man pages for OpenSC API (googling I was able to find some, but very incomplete and sporadic).

Any information would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you either use [IsoApplet](https://github.com/philipWendland/IsoApplet) (that has both JavaCard applet and OpenSC driver) or if you want to develop your own, learn from its source code.

Also, if you have studied the standards and existing applets (and drivers) you should have enough domain knowledge to get an idea of what some of the API functions do. If not, keep your code somewhere in public and you can (hopefully) get support from the OpenSC developers via mailing list.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. Your **AppletPlayground** was very helpful in studying JavaCard applets (Also **GlobalPlatformPro** is a great tool). I put much effort in studying all applet source codes I was able to find googling.  And yes I am studying their OpenSC driver counterparts, but I must admit that this task would be much easier if I were able to have OpenSC structures and functions documentation (If such documentation exists, of course, I have not been able to find that useful, although there is plenty of information on OpenSC wiki page).